# Scipy: change dtype of interpolation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numpy-dtype

Is it possible to force scipy's interpolation to output arrays with a specific numpy dtype?

For example, output a float32 array from scipy.interpolate.Rbf()?

Comment: What dtype do you get now?  Does it depend on the dtype of inputs?  It could be that Python code calls compile routines with few type options (e.g. double).  Casting after the return might be the best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you always get float64 type. For anything else, cast the output after receiving it, with `.astype(np.float32)`, etc.

I take Rbf for example: the first thing it does with input data is cast it to `np.float_`, an alias for float64. [As seen here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.0.0/scipy/interpolate/rbf.py#L191):

```
self.xi = np.asarray([np.asarray(a, dtype=np.float_).flatten()
                           for a in args[:-1]])
```

The nodes of interpolation are computed from that, so they are float64 too. The call method of Rbf object does not cast input data, but NumPy does that anyway within `np.dot`, because of the datatype of `self.nodes`:

```
return np.dot(self._function(r), self.nodes).reshape(shp)
```

Comment: This is kind of unfortunate behaviour. If attempting to interpolate a large raster (from measurement data which likely has fewer digits of precision) then a 64bit datatype causes memory limits to be reached several times earlier.